# Calling a function from another function for calculation (Python)

Tags: python, function

My problem is I'm trying to call the function cost from the other function area to do all the value return from the main function call. This is a homework and I'm stuck. The problem would be easy for me if I did not have to call the cost function from the area function and just do my calculations.

```
import math


def cost(price, area):

    return price / area

def area(size):

    radius = size / 2
    area = (radius**2) * math.pi
    finalprice = cost(price, area) / area
    return finalprice


def main():

    size = int(input("How big is your pizza?: "))
    price = float(input("How much does the whole pizza cost?: "))

    answer = area(size)
    print("${0:0.3f}".format(answer))

main()
```

Comment: homework problems are not typically answered on here unless you can show that you've tried to solve the issue yourself, and have a specific problem (not "I'm stuck")

Comment: 'price' isn't defined in the area function.  you try and use it when you call cost.

Comment: I'm not asking for answers. I just want to get a direction on something or some maybe some tips because I tried everything to my knowledge on this problem. I don't know why when I call the cost function from the area function it's saying the formal parameters are not defined. As you probably know I am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 1):

why would you divide the area twice? I guess you trying to compute what each unit square area costs for the pizza?

```
import math
def area(diameter , price):
    radius = diameter / 2
    area = (radius**2) * math.pi
    finalprice = price/ area
    return finalprice
def main():
    size = int(input("How big is your pizza?: "))
    price = float(input("How much does the whole pizza cost?: "))
    answer = area(size, price)
    print("${0:0.3f}".format(answer))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use variables which are not defined inside the scope of your area() function.

Within the area() function, we have size and price that are not defined. You pass in the size variable from your main(), but it is then renamed to diameter, and this diameter variable isn't used.

You should also pass the price variable, since you need it for your calculations.

```
def area(diameter, price):
    radius = diameter / 2
    area = (radius**2) * math.pi
    finalprice = cost(price, area) / area
    return finalprice
```

Also, be careful with integer division when calculating finalprice (and in your cost function)... This can lead to mistakes in your calculations.

Comment: Thank you! I included the price in my area function and it worked! I also did % division instead of /. Also, the diameter variable was a typo and I corrected it. It now works!